# It is correct to define singleton in C# like this?

Tags: c#

```
class MyClass
{
    private MyClass(){}

    private static MyClass instance;

    public static MyClass Instance
    {
       get
       {
          return instance=instance??new MyClass();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: In terms of multithreading absolutely no. If there is only one thread why do you need singleton? You should add locks to the code. Concerning `??` it will work, but I'd rather write it in more common way, with `if`.

Comment: Please read [Jon Skeet's Singleton patterns](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).  Your code is what is shown as the bad example in "First version - not thread-safe".

Comment: The correct way is to NOT define a singleton. Its part of the STUPID design acronym for a reason. Think SOLID design instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for noticing me about multithreading safaty , i even didn't knew about that.

Comment: When someone mentions a singleton I always wonder in what scope? Just 1 instance per thread, per (virtual) machine, cluster of machines, data center or really just 1 in the world ever?

Comment: Btw can someone provide example when my first version creates two instances of the MyClass in multiple threads ?  i've just tryed it in two threads and even put preakpoint at MyClass constructor , but it creates only one instance.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think that [singleton is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

That said:

Your code isn't safe because

```
return instance = instance ?? new MyClass();
```

is not atomic.

[`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes care of a lot of the issues regarding the creation of singleton classes.

So:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instanceLazy.Value;
        }
    }

    private static Lazy<MyClass> instanceLazy = 
        new Lazy<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());

    private MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Lazy<T> is available in .NET 4 and higher. (Reference source is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs,8b99c1f377873554) if you want to implement something similar in an earlier version.)

Comment: Thank you for response. What about thread safaty problem which mentioned above ? this satisfies multithreading safaty criterias ?

Comment: @ՀայկԳրիգորյան Yes. In its default mode, `Lazy<T>` is thread safe.